# Problems with decltype and templates

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, decltype

I have a compilation error when trying to instantiate a std::thread using decltype.I know of an workarround using lambdas, but i find it hard to understand what i am doing wrong. (maybe i am using decltype wrong).These reproduces on MSVC and GCC 8.1

```
#include<thread>

template<typename T>
class lockBasedQueue
{
private:
    std::queue<T> data_queue;
    mutable std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cond_var;

public:
    lockBasedQueue() {}
    void push(T newValue)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        data_queue.push(std::move(newValue));
        cond_var.notify_one();
    }

    void wait_and_pop(T& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cond_var.wait(lk, [this]() {return data_queue.size() > 0; });
        value = std::move(data_queue.front());
        data_queue.pop();
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return false;
    }
};


int main()
{
    lockBasedQueue<int> q;
    std::thread t1(&lockBasedQueue<int>::push, q, 10);
    typedef decltype(q) myQueue;
    std::thread t2(&myQueue::empty, q);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://rextester.com/NCCHP32416) with MSVC.

Comment: apologies for the lack of public and include thread, i should have compiled the edited snippet before posting here. I have added the extra information. This seems to compile without errors on gcc, whereas on msvc this does not compile. From your point of view am i doing any non-standard shady stuff and depending on gcc?

Comment: Add compiler error message(s) as well and compiler version

Comment: Edited the snippet a bit, i am doing something somewhere wrong, but it is just one of those days, when you are just too blind to see the obvious. Can you please try now and reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that your class contains a `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`.  This makes your class non-copyable and non-moveable.  That means

```
std::thread t1(&lockBasedQueue<int>::push, q, 10);
```

and

```
std::thread t2(&myQueue::empty, q);
```

will never work since you cant copy `q` into the thread.

What you can do though is use `&q` to get a pointer to `q` and then the thread can invoke the function pointer on that pointer.  So, your code should be

```
int main()
{
    lockBasedQueue<int> q;
    std::thread t1(&lockBasedQueue<int>::push, &q, 10);
    typedef decltype(q) myQueue;
    std::thread t2(&myQueue::empty, &q);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```